# Does python file with packages to install must be called requirements.txt?

Tags: python, package, requirements.txt

I have quick question, becouse I have a weird bug. In my code I create virtual environment for python and then install all packages from file using `pip install -r <file name>`. When I run it locally everything is ok, when I run it remotely on machine it fails and shows that some package is not installed.

I found out, that when I call file with packages needed *requirements.txt* everything works fine locally and remotely, problems apprear when I change file name.

My question is then, is there any convention about naming this file? I thought this name is just a tip and a "standard", but it appears then it is more than that.

Comment: What problem did you run into? There is no need for the file to be called requirements.txt. If I put everything into a `packages.txt` and run `python -m pip install -r packages.txt` everything runs just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Requirements files](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/installing-packages/#requirements-files) topic from python documentation you can find all explanation regarding the use of a file to install items using `pip install`. You can also check in the [User Guide](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#requirements-files), it mainly need the right file format that can also be found in [Requirements File Format](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/requirements-file-format/#requirements-file-format).

> It’s important to be clear that pip determines package dependencies
> using install_requires metadata, not by discovering requirements.txt
> files embedded in projects.

So it also works with:

```
pip install -r my_pacakges.txt
```